# mysql: COUNT returns wrong number

Tags: mysql, sql, count

everyone. I have 2 tables

## Lobby:

```
|lobby_id (pk, a_increment) | t_id | u_id |
-------------------------------------------
|1                          | 6    | 131  |
```

## Trips:

```
|tid | t_name | t_desc | max_size |
----------------------------------
|6   | GO TO HELL | DSADA | 13  |
|7   | GO TO das  | DSADA | 9   |
|7   | GO TO das  | DSADA | 9   |
```

I need to count u_id from lobby where t_id = 6 (tid in Trips table) and display: count and max_size from (trips)
my sql query so simple:

```
SELECT count(b.u_id) as counter, a.size as p_size
        from trips a
        left join lobby b ON b.t_id=6
```

But the query result show me not counter = 1 and max_size = 13, this query returs counter 3 and max_size 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a predicate matching records from both tables in the `ON` clause of your query:

```
SELECT count(b.u_id) as counter, b.max_size 
from trips a
left join lobby b ON a.tid = b.tid 
WHERE a.t_id=6
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. You save a lot of my time, cause i'm not good in sql :(

Comment: @ATIKON Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have a `join` at all:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as counter, MAX(a.size) as p_size
FROM trips t
WHERE t.tid = 6
```

All the information is in one table.

Comment: I need to count u_id from lobby.